# builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable using os.walk

Tags: python, loops, parsing, os.walk

Attempting to build a parser / fault logger for SATCOM iDirect Modem.

Looking for assistance. More specifically, I am currently stuck on line, "for x in f:". This syntax works if the file path is statically assigned to a single file, but not during an os.walk loop

Currently receiving error,"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\ACM_Scan_Tool.py", line 17, in 
    for x in f:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

```
#*My current code*

import os
rootdir = (r"C:\Users\Desktop\AUB_AES_ACM")

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".log"):
            print(file)
            f = open
            **for x in f:**
                if x.rfind('OpenAMIP: received <-- w 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0') >-1 :
                    print(x, end='')
            f.close
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `open` function in the line `f = open` so you've never opened the file. It should be `f = open(file)`. Or you could use the with statement.

```
print(file)
with open(file) as f:
    for x in f:
        if x.rfind('OpenAMIP: received <-- w 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0') >-1 :
            print(x, end='')
```

Comment: thank you, and noted. I ended up just creating a list of the paths, and then using he follwowing:with open(readf,"r") as f:
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            count = count + 1
            if count == 1: